# codeigniter 4 mysql query distinct or groupby

Tags: php, codeigniter, mariadb

I'm using codeigniter-4.1.9. I have a score table and there have multiple round. each user getting there scores in different rounds. I want to retrieve each users score in a single row with different rounds but unable to get expected result. How to fix this?

I tried both :

```
$scmodel->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM score GROUP BY score");
```

OR

```
$scmodel->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM score GROUP BY teamid");
```

expected Result should:

```
teamid round1 round2 round3
 1       20       30      40
 2       50       30      90
 3       45       38      70
```

But Getting:

```
teamid round1 round2 round3
  1      20
  2      50
  3      45
  1              30
  2              30
  3              38
  1                       40
  2                       90
  3                       70
```

Score Table are

[image]

Comment: please provide your table stucture also.

Comment: The table structure has already been added to the post.  Just without ID.  Here the ID is just increasing automatically per entry.

Comment: so how you store and inserted multiple round scores data same as expected Result data?

Comment: Both round and score are separate table.when insert score for each round in score table just pick round id from round table by drop Down list.

Comment: you want to get scores of round on the basis of teamid?

Comment: and please add your database tag also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243340/discussion-between-kumar-and-styled-bee).

Comment: the below answer will satisfied your needs???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the rounds as separate columns you need to make a `pivot query` something like this:

```
$scmodel->query("
  SELECT teamid, 
  SUM(IF(roundid = 1, score, 0)) as round1,
  SUM(IF(roundid = 2, score, 0)) as round2,
  SUM(IF(roundid = 3, score, 0)) as round3
FROM score
GROUP BY teamid
");
```

**SAMPLE DATA:**

```
create table score (id integer(3), 
                   teamid varchar(100), 
                   jid integer(3), 
                   roundid integer(3), 
                   challengeid integer(3), 
                   score integer(5), 
                   mailstatus integer(3)
                   );

insert into score values
  (1, 'CTO202241400-GOLD', 2, 2, 4, 89, 1),
  (2, 'CTO20220171-DIAM', 2, 1, 3, 75, 1),
  (3, 'CTO-2022-1133224-ZOOM', 2, 1, 4, 87, 1),
  (4, 'CTO20221888-EAGL', 2, 2, 4, 76, 1),
  (5, 'CTO2022889-ABGR', 2, 3, 5, 59, 1),
  (6, 'CTO202241400-GOLD', 2, 3, 5, 89, 1),
  (7, 'CTO20221888-EAGL', 2, 3, 5, 97, 1),
  (8, 'CTO-2022-1133224-ZOOM', 2, 3, 5, 67, 1),
  (9, 'CTO20220171-DIAM', 2, 3, 5, 98, 1);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
| teamid                | round1 | round2 | round3 |
|-----------------------|--------|--------|--------|
| CTO-2022-1133224-ZOOM | 87     | 0      | 67     |
| CTO20220171-DIAM      | 75     | 0      | 98     |
| CTO20221888-EAGL      | 0      | 76     | 97     |
| CTO202241400-GOLD     | 0      | 89     | 89     |
| CTO2022889-ABGR       | 0      | 0      | 59     |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ed3fa/3/0

Comment: Thanx So much!! Well done... Could you please explain how this query works?

Comment: @StyledBee I am Happy this answers will works for you.

Comment: @StyledBee SUM() is an aggregate function you can use with the GROUP BY clause in SQL. More reading about how it works: https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php